# Can I acces my local network devices from XAMPP?

Tags: javascript, ajax, arduino

I have a arduino and ethernet shield. I have temperature meter. On my arduino site, I display it. On my subpage there's only temperature, without html tags etc. I want to do ajax request. Can I do this from my xampp, to get the temperature?
So:
Can I do ajax request to another device in my local network?
Thanks a lot

Comment: yes, you can do it

Comment: if CORS makes you troubles, use `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"` in reponse

Comment: Can you tell me, why this isnt working? I added ajax.response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") and it doesnt work :/

Comment: I don't see your code